# Density boundaries in a scatter plot

Tags: terminology, scatterplot

Let's say I have a scatter plot with (X, Y) real numbers. 
Looking at the scatter plot I see a clear boundary, a curve or a line that I could sketch so that the density of points below the line is much greater than the density of those above.

Is there a name for this? I call it a "density boundary" Are there numerical methods to find such a boundary and quantify how significant it is?

I could integrate to find the area below and above the function that I think defines the boundary, count the number of points contained and excluded and compare the points/area^2. The greater the difference the more likely it is a "real" boundary...

But I'm wondering if there is something more formal, what it might be called to find that boundary...

Comment: This seems to be something that might be recognised informally but is hard to specify and test formally. I don't know any recognised terminology for this. The only checks I can think of are whether the same feature is discernible with other, especially larger samples, or in simulations. You don't say what kind of data or how large a sample: I would worry especially about over-interpreting patterns with small samples.

Comment: One name given to such patterns has been "illusion."  That doesn't mean *your* pattern isn't real, but it does indicate you need great care in assessing this *post hoc* hypothesis.  It would help to understand the context, the meaning of these numbers, how they were collected, the purpose of your analysis, and what the implications of any conclusions might be.  (cc @Nick)

Comment: Another word that some people bandy around is _apophenia_,

Comment: This isn't about a particular set of data it's just something I've noticed from time to time in varying degrees of intensity. Some real others illusions most likely. I wanted tools to determine if a density pattern is significant, predictive... real.